# How do i remove 'availability in stock' display from magento category view

Tags: magento, stock, availability

I run a Magento store which we want to run without stock management but with all items displayed regardless of stock status.

I have switched off stock management & have everything I want showing but I cannot find a way to remove the 'Availability: In Stock' message from search results, category & brand views.  How can I stop this from showing?

I have found an edit to the style.css file but this only removes it from product pages & not from search results, category & brand lists.

Comment: Either use inspect element in your browser to determine what to hide with CSS, or navigate to your theme's /catalog/product/list.phtml and comment it out from there - also any other phtml files that search etc may be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be in your theme's list.phtml file. Go here;

```
Mage Root/app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/catalog/product/list.html
```

You will find the logic for displaying the message in there.

XXX/YYY will be the path of your particular theme.  In the unlikely event that your theme doesnt have a list.phtml file, then check here;

```
Mage Root/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.2.4 this is in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml` and `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/composite.phtml` you are supposed to write your own in `app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/` or in `app/design/frontend/MYPACKAGE/MYTHEME/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/`

Otherwhise drop

```
.availability-only {
  display: none;
}
```

into style.css

Answer (score 0):

navigate to styles.css and scroll down until you find /* Availability */ and change the first line underneath to read:-
.availability { margin:0;display:none; }

If you have configurable products you will need to re-index the catalogue to re-link the child products. Also clear all caches.